# AVPlayerViewController forward and rewind button disabled for hls stream but working for mp4 stream

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

AVPlayerViewController forward/rewind buttons beside the play button do not seem to work for HLS, but work for an mp4 stream (non - local, played from internet). How can I get it working for HLS? Is there any separate way to make it work for HLS?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by the player. 
You can disable those buttons using the code below:

```
if([playerItem canStepBackward] && [playerItem canStepForward]){
        [playerViewController setShowsPlaybackControls:YES];
    }
    else{
        [playerViewController setShowsPlaybackControls:NO];
    }
```